# Tool for finding the database bottlenecks in sql server

Tags: sql-server, profiling

I would like a tool that monitors sql server while I test my application. THe applicatino will of course run different queries.

From the tool I would like an output like:
- this query was slow because index is missing on this field

and this kind of info.

But I'd like to have a way to highlight crucial data, there can be for example 100 index missing, but 99 of them would improve the performance of 0.05%, while one of those would give a 6000% benefit on a query. So Highlighting hot spots is important too.

Also a commercial product (with full features - no limited - trial) is desired.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't exactly need a tool. I personally use the following query to show me what indexes SQL Server thinks it needs, this shows how often SQL Server looked for the index, estimated improvement etc...

```
SELECT user_seeks * avg_total_user_cost * (avg_user_impact * 0.01) AS index_advantage,
   migs.last_user_seek,
   mid.statement AS 'Database.Schema.Table',
   mid.equality_columns,
   mid.inequality_columns,
   mid.included_columns,
   migs.unique_compiles,
   migs.user_seeks,
   migs.avg_total_user_cost,
   migs.avg_user_impact
FROM sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats AS migs WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups AS mig WITH (NOLOCK) 
    ON migs.group_handle = mig.index_group_handle
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_details AS mid WITH (NOLOCK) 
    ON mig.index_handle = mid.index_handle
ORDER BY index_advantage DESC;
```

If you want to identify slow queries SQL Profiler is your friend, just set a filter on duration and you're set. Then run this query through the Database Engine Tuning Advisor (both come with SQL Server).

Comment: I just run that query on one of my databases. Could you add a link to a document that explains how to interpret the results ? Thanks !

Comment: Found it: http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/sarveshsingh/archive/2010/08/23/index-usage.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187974%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx there you go :)

Comment: yes very cool, but i don't really understand the "advantage" of some indexes, I tried to create some and see no effect even if the "advantage" is high, while others are in fact very useful

Comment: Well some of these indexes will say they are a big improvement because they improve a query that is run ALOT a little. Meaning the sql server isn't stressed as much but the query times won't change alot.

Answer (score 2):

- SQL Server Profiler
- SQL Database Advisor

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at SQL Copilot. There is a free version, and the full version is cheap (around 50$).
Note that while I use it and found it usefull in order to raise some issues and as a learning tool, I am still looking for other tools as well.
There is a lot to learn on this tricky subject (un)fortunaltely.